# Is this series convergent or divergent ? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \ln(n)}{n} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \ln(n)}{n} $$

How do I determine if this converges or diverges?     I should be able to show this with just the basic library of Calc II tests (Geometric, p-series, Divergence (nth term) test, Integral test, Direct Comparison test, Alternating Series Test, or Ratio test) None of these involved derivatives, either

Comment: You should also realize that users can see your question history, and can track whether or not you are (re)posting duplicate questions, which is against site policy.  Again:  (1) don't do it.  (2) it's pointless, anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the integral test on the absolute series. You will get that it diverges. Then, using the alternating series test, you will get that the series is conditionally convergent.

$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (x)}{x} dx = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left( \lim_{t\to \infty} \ln ^2|t| - \ln ^2(1)\right) = \infty$

Then, since $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is monotonically decreasing for all $n\geq 2$,  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n} =0$, and the absolute series diverges, the series is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Note that since $(\ln n)/n > 1/n$ for $n \geq 3$, you could also prove divergence of the absolute series via comparison to the harmonic series.

Comment: I took the integral of the absolute series, the absolute value of $(-1)^x$ is just 1.

Comment: To show a series converges conditionally it must diverge absolutely

Comment: Ok, so your integral test was to show the absolute series diverged?  I did that using direct comparison against harmonic.  Was simpler.  So, I am now just interested in how to show the original series converges.  You just used Alt. Series test for that part?  But, the orig. series is not decreasing.  0,.35,.37,.35, etc

Comment: Well you can use the comparison test as well. There's often multiple ways to show series diverge. The original series will converge conditionally cause of reasons stated above in my answer

Comment: How do you prove that $\frac{ln(n)}{n}$ is decreasing once you get past the first few terms?

Comment: Take derivatives and show that its negative for all $n$ would work, but it's a well known fact that $\ln (n) < n$ for all $n > 0$

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{ln(x)}{x}$ is $\frac{1-ln(x)}{x^2}$   You show that is always negative since ln(x) is always bigger than 1, once x > 2.  Got it!!

Comment: $\ln (x) >1$ for all $x > e$

Answer (score 2):

It's convergent, and we have:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\ln(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}\left(2\gamma\ln(2) - \ln^2(2)\right) \approx 0.159869$$

Where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Hint: Alternating Term Series Test.

Comment: How did you calculate the value? I've never seen this one before...